# Error in my spring-hibernate application

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am new to Spring, i am trying to create a simple project with spring and Hibernate with annotations(without use of configuration and mapping XML's). I am held up with this below error since 3 days.

**Here is the error i see..**

```
`ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Spring]] (MSC service thread 1-2) StandardWrapper.Throwable: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) [org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321) [org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:830) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:591) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) [org.springframework.context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469) [org.springframework.context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider from [Module "deployment.Spring.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
... 32 more

16:42:59,393 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Spring]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Servlet /Spring threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider from [Module "deployment.Spring.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) [org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321) [org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:830) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:591) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) [org.springframework.context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469) [org.springframework.context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]`
```

**Here is the code**

```
[ Spring-servlet.xml]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.spring.form.Items</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">${hibernate.connection.pool_size}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />

<tx:annotation-driven />


</beans>

Controller


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.spring.form.Items;
import com.spring.service.ReceiptsService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/receiptsnew")
public class ReceiptsSpringController {

@Autowired
private ReceiptsService receiptsService;

public ReceiptsSpringController()
{

}

@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveItems(@ModelAttribute("item")Items item, BindingResult result)
{
    receiptsService.addItem(item);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/receiptsnew.html");

}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewItems()
{
    Map model= new HashMap();
    model.put("items", receiptsService.getAllItems());
    //items is just a key values

    return new ModelAndView("itemsView",model);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addItems(@ModelAttribute("item")Items item, BindingResult result) 
{
    return new ModelAndView("itemAdd"); 
}
}

DAO



import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import com.spring.form.Items;
@Repository("itemDao")
public class HibernateItemDao implements ItemDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public void saveItem(Items item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Items> getAllItems() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Items.class).list();
}

}




Service layer  


import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.spring.dao.ItemDao;
import com.spring.form.Items;



@Service("receiptsService")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly=true)
public class ReceiptsServiceImpl implements ReceiptsService {

@Autowired
private ItemDao itemDao;

public ReceiptsServiceImpl()
{
}


@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false)
public void addItem(Items item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    itemDao.saveItem(item);
}

public List<Items> getAllItems() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemDao.getAllItems();
}

}

Form data


@Entity
@Table(name="INVP200B") 
public class Items {

@Id
@Column(name="ITEMB")
private String itemno;

@Column(name="QUARTB")
private String quantity;

@Column(name="QTYPLB")
private String pallet;

public Items()
{

}

public String getItemno() {
    return itemno;
}

public void setItemno(String itemno) {
    this.itemno = itemno;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getPallet() {
    return pallet;
}

public void setPallet(String pallet) {
    this.pallet = pallet;
}

public String toString()
{
    return " ITEM NO IS "+itemno+" QUANTITY IS"+quantity+" PALLET QUANTITY IS "+pallet ;
}
}

properties
database.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.connection.pool_size=10
database.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@app11.corebusiness.com\:2521\:oracle1
database.username=Alleg
database.password=Alleg
```

The following is the list of jars: https://i.stack.imgur.com/18rKU.png

I used to get "error-creating-bean-sessionfactory -nested exception" until i changed the order of my bean declarations in the spring-servlet code.

Comment: The code is mentioned in this post already(below the error text).. Sorry if my indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As a solution to the the following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.j‌​ava:207)

Please define the following entry for sessionFactory

```
<prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
```

Comment: Not sure but this works. I have tried every other fix and didn't work. Thanks for sharing  (Y)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing hibernate3 and hibernate4 classes:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                                              ^-- 4
...

<bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
                                              ^-- 3
```

Make sure to only use classes from the hibernate4 package if you're using Hibernate 4, or to only use classes from the hibernate3 package if you're using Hibernate 3.

Moreover, it seems you're running this inside JBoss. Why not use its JTA transaction manager then?

Comment: Hello JB Nizet, i tried using "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" .. but end up with the below error                              `Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Analyze the full stack trace. I can't guess what the reason is for that.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:207) [hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final.jar:4.1.3.Final]                          Could you tell me why the above error may be caused?

Comment: I have even tried using the JTA transaction manager, but continue to get the same "Null Pointer" error that is mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

The exception above can be resolved by adding this Hibernate property:

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

as you're using annotations you have to use AnnotationSessionFactoryBean class

change this

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory"   
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

to

```
     <bean id="sessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
```

Comment: I started with using the class ""org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" "but i get the following error, hence had to change it to "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"       `ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Spring]] (MSC service thread 1-2) StandardWrapper.Throwable: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;`

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;

Comment: can you edit your question with full stack trace of error you got when you used annotation class!

Comment: yes, i have changed the stack trace...for  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"

Comment: what version of spring you using ? ,it seems there is compatible issue https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8096?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel ,use hibernate 3.6.x all willbe good :)

Comment: As shown in the screen shot of jars, i am using hibernate 4.x (hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final)...I will try with hibernate 3.6.x and let you know about the result..Would it be a problem if i use org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE with hibernate-core-4.1.3.Final??

Comment: i tried using hibernate 3.6.x... but using hibernate 3.6.x with hibernate 3 classes did not work..In fact could not deploy the project either.. Received "resource not available"  errror.

Comment: hmm , what you mean by resource not available ?

Comment: strange!, what's the reason for not deployed successfully?